# What's the difference between "Update URL alias" and "Update automatic nodetitles" in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, pathauto

These options appear on the admin page /admin/content/node in the "Update options" drop-down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url aliasses are fake addresses, while a page may be stored at /node/13 the alias makes it so you can see the page at /this-website-is-cool

The automatic nodetitles option is related to a seperate module, the "[Automatic nodetitles](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle)" module, which does something entirely unrelated

Comment: Yep exactly, they're two two different things.

Comment: Heh.  I realized that I knew both these things.  For some reason I thought Update automatic nodetitles was something to do with URLs; I imagine because I am using titles as part of pathauto's functionality.  Sorry for the dumb question.